# Jboss AS7 Resteasy sample Oauth2 skeleton key deploy NoClassDefFoundError from PoolingClientConnectionManager

Tags: java, jboss, resteasy

Running the default Skeleton Key example with Jboss AS7 and Resteasy, I have followed the directions exactly here: https://github.com/resteasy/Resteasy/tree/master/jaxrs/examples/oauth2-as7-example but still get an error on deploy:

> 14:35:10,453 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext] (MSC
>   service thread 1-11) Context [/customer-portal] startup failed due to
>   previous errors: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/apache/http/impl/conn/PoolingClientConnectionManager  at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.ResteasyClientBuilder.initDefaultEngine(ResteasyClientBuilder.java:428)
>   [resteasy-client-3.0.6.Final.jar:]    at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.ResteasyClientBuilder.build(ResteasyClientBuilder.java:333)
>   [resteasy-client-3.0.6.Final.jar:]    at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.skeleton.key.as7.OAuthManagedResourceValve.init(OAuthManagedResourceValve.java:115)
>   [skeleton-key-as7-3.0.6.Final.jar:]   at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.skeleton.key.as7.OAuthManagedResourceValve.lifecycleEvent(OAuthManagedResourceValve.java:66)
>   [skeleton-key-as7-3.0.6.Final.jar:]   at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:115)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3845)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]  at
>   org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:90)
>   [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]    at
>   org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
>     at
>   org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>   [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>   [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
>   [rt.jar:1.7.0_25] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingClientConnectionManager from [Module
>   "org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs:main" from local module loader
>   @1d1aed21 (roots: /Users/JamesTruty/work/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final
>   oauth/modules)]   at
>   org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190)
>     at
>   org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468)
>     at
>   org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456)
>     at
>   org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
>     at
>   org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120)
>     ... 12 more

I have tried various ways of trying to include the apache httpclient library, but still no luck. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

A `NoClassDefFoundError` specifies that the particular library was available during compile time, but missing at runtime. You need to make sure that `httpclient jar` is present in your classpath. If it is present then it might be having a static initialization failure or is being loaded via a different classloader. You can go through this for any further info on [how to debug a NoClassDefFoundError](http://javareferencegv.blogspot.com/2013/10/debugging-javalangnoclassdeffounderror.html)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, after more tweaking I got it to successfully deploy the sample app. I needed to update the jar versions and modify the module xml in Jboss to point to org.apache.httpcomponents to use httpclient-4.2.1.jar, httpcore-4.2.1.jar and httpmime-4.2.1.jar.